# 413 error in apache even though my POST is much smaller than the max limit

Tags: httpd, fedora, httpd.conf, curl, http-status-code

I have asked this question on stack overflow as well. I have an apache server and a fastcgi script. When I try to send POST request to my script, it fails giving me the 413 error. If I send in no parameters, my script actually runs giving me error in json (as expected).

I am using curl to send data to my script:

```
curl --data -v 'name=test&address=abc&phoneNumber=0987654321&password=test123' http://localhost/cgi-bin/add-user.fcg
```

It gives this output:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /cgi-bin/add-user.fcg HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 61
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 61 out of 61 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
< Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 03:43:48 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Fedora) mod_fcgid/2.3.9
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head><body><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></body></html>
```

I am sending 61 bytes! I feel that is too low for this error. This is what I have done till now:

1. I did not have LimitRequestBody in my httpd.conf, so it should have been defaulted to 0 (aka unlimited). But still, I added `LimitRequestBody 1024000` and restarted the server
2. Then I read somewhere that mod_security might have interfered. So I added `<IfModule secruity2_module>
   SecRequestBody Off
   </IfModule>`
    but to no avail

This is my httpd.conf:
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

```
Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>


    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

#I added the line below
LimitRequestBody 1024000 

<IfModule secruity2_module>
    SecRequestBody Off
</IfModule>
```

I then changed the log level to debug. This is the error_log:

```
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196028 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196893 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196926 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196931 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.6.3"; loaded version="1.6.5"
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196935 2019] [:warn] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: Loaded APR do not match with compiled!
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196939 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.42 "; loaded version="8.43 2019-02-23"
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196946 2019] [:warn] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: Loaded PCRE do not match with compiled!
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196949 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.3"
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196952 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.1.0"
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196956 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.8"
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196959 2019] [:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.196968 2019] [http2:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_http2.c(112): AH03089: initializing post config dry run
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.218065 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH01574: module security2_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.221248 2019] [slotmem_shm:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_slotmem_shm.c(496): AH02301: attach looking for /run/httpd/slotmem-shm-mod_heartmonitor_0.shm
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.221287 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224000 2019] [http2:info] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH03090: mod_http2 (v1.14.1-git, feats=CHPRIO+SHA256+INVHD+DWINS, nghttp2 1.34.0), initializing...
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224058 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224046 2019] [fcgid:info] [pid 2883:tid 140595868158208] mod_fcgid: Process manager 2883 started
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224180 2019] [proxy_http2:info] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH03349: mod_proxy_http2 (v1.14.1-git, nghttp2 1.34.0), initializing...
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224211 2019] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(1050): AH03265: watchdog callback registered (_proxy_hcheck_ for localhost.localdomain)
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224234 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(454): AH010033: Watchdog: Running with WatchdogInterval 1000ms
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224241 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(462): AH02974: Watchdog: found parent providers.
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224247 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02977: Watchdog: found child providers.
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224252 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(516): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_singleton_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224256 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(516): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_default_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224261 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(516): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.224275 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(542): AH02979: Watchdog: Created singleton mutex (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.229631 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Fedora) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.229659 2019] [mpm_event:info] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH00490: Server built: Jan 23 2019 12:39:31
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.229669 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.229674 2019] [core:debug] [pid 2881:tid 140595868158208] log.c(1571): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.232979 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595820508928] mod_watchdog.c(158): AH02972: Singleton Watchdog (_proxy_hcheck_) running
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.232987 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.233085 2019] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595820508928] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(893): AH03258: _proxy_hcheck_ watchdog started.
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.233333 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1927): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.233365 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1984): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.233409 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(2019): AH00930: initialized pool in child 2885 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.234163 2019] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595820508928] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(907): AH03313: apr_thread_pool_create() with 16 threads succeeded
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.235043 2019] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595292866304] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.236319 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.236395 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1927): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.236456 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1984): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.236488 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(2019): AH00930: initialized pool in child 2886 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.237535 2019] [:warn] [pid 2884:tid 140595868158208] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.237654 2019] [watchdog:debug] [pid 2887:tid 140595868158208] mod_watchdog.c(590): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.237715 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2887:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1927): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.237739 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2887:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(1984): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.237766 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2887:tid 140595868158208] proxy_util.c(2019): AH00930: initialized pool in child 2887 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.239266 2019] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595501586176] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Mar 26 09:04:40.239529 2019] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2887:tid 140595501586176] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Mar 26 09:05:42.487165 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595284473600] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client ::1:34770] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Mar 26 09:05:42.487347 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2885:tid 140595284473600] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client ::1:34770] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Mar 26 09:05:42.496956 2019] [fcgid:info] [pid 2883:tid 140595868158208] mod_fcgid: server localhost.localdomain:/var/www/cgi-bin/add-user.fcg(3148) started
[Tue Mar 26 09:13:48.452071 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595418887936] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client ::1:34974] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Mar 26 09:13:48.452192 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2886:tid 140595418887936] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client ::1:34974] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

And this is the access log:

```
::1 - - [26/Mar/2019:09:05:42 +0530] "POST /cgi-bin/add-user.fcg HTTP/1.1" 413 144 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
::1 - - [26/Mar/2019:09:13:48 +0530] "POST /cgi-bin/add-user.fcg HTTP/1.1" 413 144 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the call to the Apache Server at 09:05:42

```
::1 - - [26/Mar/2019:09:05:42 +0530] "POST /cgi-bin/add-user.fcg HTTP/1.1" 413 144 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
```

correctly started the CGI Script

```
[Tue Mar 26 09:05:42.496956 2019] [fcgid:info] [pid 2883:tid 140595868158208] mod_fcgid: server localhost.localdomain:/var/www/cgi-bin/add-user.fcg(3148) started
```

So the Response Code `413` might come from your Script itself.

It would be useful to see what Content reaches your Script.

Comment: Yeah. Actually that was the problem, My FASTCGI library had POST request disabled by default.